# Can we use against with complain

Tags: prepositions

Everybody complains against callous treatment of the the police.

I believe we do not use **against** with the word **complain** because complain in itself means something against.
Can you please clarify this doubt.
Thank you.

Comment: You're correct. It should be *complain **about** callous treatment*

Comment: @GrahamNicol so, it can be both complains of or complains about, I believe both would be correct.

Comment: If you say "complains of", it would have to be: *Everybody complains of callous treatment by the the police.*

Comment: Why don't you ask OALD,  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/complain?q=complain

Answer (score 2):

*Complain **against*** is not ungrammatical, but it is very rare outside of legal contexts, where *complain* has the sense *lay a formal complaint or pleading*. It is used only with persons, natural or corporate, as object of the preposition, because only persons can be sued.

So you might say that indignant citizens bringing suit against the police department for some misconduct "complained against the police". But in your example what you probably mean is

> Everybody complains about the treatment of [somebody—criminals?] by the police

meaning that the police mistreated the criminals.

And you probably mean that the treatment was *harsh* or *severe* rather than *callous* = "unfeeling, hard-hearted".

Answer (score 1):

The word *'Complain'* is always targeted at something or someone. It is also a negative impact verb. There is no need to double negate it with a word like *'against'*. It is irrelevant and meaningless to do so. You are 100% correct with your assumption.

Comment: Well, I could say "She just likes to complain." or "Stop complaining and eat your dinner." Complain doesn't have to be targeted at something or someone, unless I'm misunderstanding your meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *'to complain'* doesn't collocate with the preposition *against*, but the noun *'complaint'* does. So you can [have/bring/ make a complaint against the police](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=complaint).